# Get seed based on id and date with minimal number of objects

Tags: java, optimization

I need to create a seed for shuffling and the seed should be based on an id (int) and the current date (without the time). This is to preserve the ordering for an id for a single day and change it the next day. I have got the following method for this now:

```
private static long getSeedForShuffle(int id)
{
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = MyConstants.UTC_CALENDAR;
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    double seed = id * 1e8 + year * 1e4 + month * 1e2 + day;
    return (long) seed;
}
```

and this in MyConstants:

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static final Calendar UTC_CALENDAR = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                                                       .getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

Is there any way to avoid creating the new date object every time the method is invoked? i.e. is there something better than doing

```
Date date = new Date();
```

in the `getSeedForShuffle` method, since all this method needs is the current day, month and year, which can, in principle, be generated only once daily?

NOTE: This code is running in a web application.

(Started thinking about this after reading Effective Java Item 5: Avoid creating unnecessary objects.)

Comment: I would not call that specific example an unnecessary object creation, because recycling the object will create all sorts of issues (such as thread safety for example) which are not worth the gain IMO (unless that method is called hundreds of times per second). Also, is there a strong reason why you want the seed to be based on the date? A simple incrementing counter (if you need the ordering) or even a random number (if ordering is not important) would be easier.

Comment: We need to maintain the order for a day since we are doing some A/B testing. Our pages are cached for a few minutes, but cannot afford a new random order every time the object is created.

Comment: Also if you use a database (at least SQL, probably others too), you can easily get a "universal" unique incrementing id.

Comment: Don't forget that Calendar is not thread-safe. If you want prevent allocation, use ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public long seed(int id, long time) {
   return id ^ (time / 86400000L)
}

 have fun
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not compiled this, but might give you an idea. Store a timestamp of midnight and then its easy to see if you're 24 hours later than that using the System time call.

```
private static final long ONE_DAY = 1000l * 60 * 60 * 24;
private static long midnight = 0;
private static double seed = 0;

private static long getSeedForShuffle(int id)
{
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - ONE_DAY > midnight) {
      Date date = new Date();
      Calendar cal = MyConstants.UTC_CALENDAR;
      cal.setTime(date);
      int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      seed = id * 1e8 + year * 1e4 + month * 1e2 + day;
      midnight = new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
    }
    return (long) seed;
}
```

Comment: I get the idea. The seed depends on the id, so you would keep only the date portion stored and add in the id portion in the method.

Comment: You should probably make `midnight` volatile and not use a shared `seed` variable (otherwise you have a race condition and ordering is not guaranteed any more).

Comment: He just wants to avoid object creation. Admittedly in mine you could generate the seed multiple times, but always with the same result, and it would only happen on a race condition on the day roll over. So I wouldn't tend to bother with synchronization or volatile unless that was an issue.

Comment: One more thing, to support my case, set the minutes,hours,seconds to zero to ensure seed is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

This problem boils down to generating a "random", but consistent `long` for a given date and id.

To increase the quality (pseudo randomness) of your seed, use the wrapper `hashCode()` for each part:

```
private static long getSeedForShuffle(int id) {
    return Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.toDays(System.currentTimeMillis())).hashCode() << 32
      + Integer.valueOf(id).hashCode();
}
```

Points here:

- Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get "now"
- Use `TimeUnit.toDays()` to convert "now" to days
- Use `hashCode()` to create a consistent, but pseudo random (high quality) seed value
- Left shift one of the int hashCode values into the high half of a long so all bits of the hashCodes participate in the result
- Avoid using `Calendar`, which is arguably the most broken class in the JDK

Although this code creates a Long and an Integer, those objects are extremely light weight, and the JIT compiler would likely in-line the hashCode generation code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each day has the same length, you don't need to allocate anything (expect in the static initializer, and even this could be eliminated).

```
private static final long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24;
private static final long SOME_MIDNIGHT_MILLIS;
static {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    SOME_MIDNIGHT_MILLIS = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private static long getSeedForShuffle(int id) {
    final long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - SOME_MIDNIGHT_MILLIS;
    long days = millis / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
    return 123456789 * days + id;
}
```